# Start Date of the Week as Wednesday in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I wanted to aggregate my data based on first day as Wednesday. I had an `event_date` column on which I wanted to do this.

Thanks in advance!

My Current solution was a long hardcoded `case when` conditions which are unscalable to continue.

```
 case when event_date between '2023-08-16' and '2023-08-22' then '1. 16-22'
            when event_date between '2023-08-23' and '2023-08-29' then '2. 23-29'
            when event_date between '2023-08-30' and '2023-09-05' then '3. 30-5'
            end as time_line,
```

Comment: what's wrong with using DATE_PART() ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shift your date to 5 days(The difference between Wednesday and next Monday), after truncate date to Monday and shift it back to Wednesday.

```sql
select DATE_TRUNC('week', event_date + '5 day'::interval)::date - '5 day'::interval as date_wednesday;
```